# How to read same filenames from different directory in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, path, directory

For instance, there are some folders in an application in which there are a series of pics with the format 00#.jpg. Now, suppose two buttons. A button can get the path of /FolderA/001.jpg and B Button can get the path of /FolderB/002.jpg. Which method should I use?

Comment: Xcode is not a programming language. Are you working in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

You Dont have to give any path for images even if it is in any folder in your xcode project. U just need to specify their names.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

NOTE : USE .png images not always are the .jpg supported